Node.js Call to SSO API & Capture JWT Response for Other API Calls
Totally new to Node.js and I'm working on authenticating to a product API. Though I've done this with Basic Auth, I need to update to with a JWT Response.

Call SSO API token with a Cert.
Capture this JWT Response.
Send JWT response from first API to product API as Authentication
Display Product Data.

While I am already doing #4, and 3 with Basic Auth, I've not had to do 1 and 2 before and running into different Promise errors, etc.
My Ask is, when searching on how to do this, I'm only finding User Management Tutorials on logging in users and assigning them different access levels (already doing this, and not what I need.) Anyone aware of a tutorial, book, video, audio in how to do this? Again, I'm new to Node.js and just need a guided step. Even tried to pay someone to teach me and they couldn't figure it out...
